# shutil.move throwing errors if processing time takes too long

Tags: python, io

I have a python program that picks up some files, runs them through a machine learning model and writes the output file to another folder. It also moves the unprocessed file to another folder to indicate that it has already been processed by the program. Here is the code that performs those actions.

```
    for f in files:
        try:
            if path.exists(path.join(processed_folder, f)):
                print(f'File {f} has already been processed')
                shutil.move(path.join(folder_to_moniter, f), path.join(processed_folder, f))
            else:
                print(f'Started processing  file "{f}"')
                convert_questionniare_using_ml(f, folder_to_moniter, modelFilesPath, keywords_list)
                shutil.move(path.join(folder_to_moniter, f), path.join(processed_folder, f))
                time.sleep(10)
                print(f'Completed processing file "{f}"')
                
        except Exception:
            shutil.move(path.join(folder_to_moniter, f), error_folder)
            print(f'Error Occurred"{Exception.with_traceback()}"')
```

The model also reads the training data from another folder and trains itself each time that "convert_questionnaire_using_ml" is called. I'll be updating this in the future to only train itself when we want to update the model. I'm also updating the model to oversample one of the target classes to improve its performance. However, when I do this, the training data becomes larger, so the model takes longer to train. For some reason, this causes the "shutil.move" method to malfunction, throwing a stack of errors.

The errors indicate that the file in "folder_to_monitor" could not be found when moving from "folder_to_monitor" to "processed_folder." However, in the file system, everything is executed correctly. The file is moved to where it's supposed to and the output file is generated.

Really confused about why this is happening. The file is not supposed to be moved until the "convert_questionnaire_using_ml" function is complete. The file does, in fact, move but the console output says otherwise.

I made several changes to the code, but finally determined that this error does not occur until the oversampling of the training data takes place. I can only imagine that the length of time it takes to train is somehow affecting the execution of the code.

Here is the edited stack trace if it's helpful:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "App.py", line 125, in main
    shutil.move(path.join(folder_to_moniter, f), path.join(processed_folder, f))
  File "C:\tools\Anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\shutil.py", line 564, in move
    copy_function(src, real_dst)
  File "C:\tools\Anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\shutil.py", line 263, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\tools\Anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\shutil.py", line 120, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'folder_to_monitor\f'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\tools\Anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\shutil.py", line 550, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'folder_to_monitor\f' -> 'error_folder\f' 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "App.py", line 135, in <module>
    main()
  File "App.py", line 130, in main
    shutil.move(path.join(folder_to_moniter, f), error_folder)
  File "C:\tools\Anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\shutil.py", line 564, in move
    copy_function(src, real_dst)
  File "C:\tools\Anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\shutil.py", line 263, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\tools\Anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\shutil.py", line 120, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'folder_to_monitor\f'
```

Comment: See [ask]. Focus on a specific implementation. Post a [mre] with debugging details including stack traces. I must be incorrectly interpreting the result.

Comment: @relent95 I can't post too much as the information is sensitive. I feel like it's pretty straightforward though. I'll post an edited stack trace, but perhaps a question would help me understand what you're confused about.

Comment: You can write a [mre] with stub functions and dummy data. Anyway, you must be incorrectly interpreting the log. Check the log for all the ```f``` values in the ```files```, file by file.